# How do I remove the product thumbnail link from a specific div in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, html

I have a section on my front page that displays the top 4 most popular products from my Woocommerce shop. I is located within a div as such:

```
<div id="trending">
    <p class="trending-title">Trending Products</p>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[best_selling_products per_page="4"]'); ?>
</div>
```

I want to remove the fact that the thumbnail image is clickable. I don't mean removing the 'add to basket' button but the thumbnail image is clickable and takes you to the individual product page. I initially though to edit the product-image.php file but I don't want to affect this feature across the entire site just in that div 'trending'. Does anyone know of how I can accomplish this? Thank you in advance for any answers and suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can for example target the link itself inside the trending id with CSS and remove the action with CSS itself, in your place it would be something like this:

```
#trending > li.product > a {

   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;

}
```

Note that this is CSS scheme, not exact CSS, that deppends on classes you have (I would be more specific if you provided link). But the point is you are targeting `<li>` inside `#trending` id and link inside `<li>` itself and you are disabling any events, so that will do the job.

I hope this helps.

Comment: So please rate answer for sake of other users for better orientation.